# AAA batteries solar charging help needed

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have a project running on 2 regular AAA batteries, I'd like to
convert it to NiMH or NiCd rechargable batteries using solar power.
I wanna use a panel like this:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008DFW1WE/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i01](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008DFW1WE)

It's cheap and it's slow on I enough. I know that you can't exceed 0.1C
recharge for NiCD at temps below -18C

So I'm looking for a slow constant 3.3V chip for that.

Space is limited. This is an outdoor project. We designed it initially for 2 alkaline AAAs, but later thought it would be nice to use rechargable AAAs (NiCd or NiMH, doesn't matter) and if solar is n/a, a user can switch it back to regular AAAs.

I've found this chip http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00287506.pdf

There is also EV board for it with more info: STEVAL-ISV006V2
Is this a good idea?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very partial answer to start. More as/if wanted:

You need a maximum of about 3V AT the battery so a 4V panel would work well and a lower one say 3.5V Vmp (voltage at maximum power) is probably OK.

Maximum capacity of an AAA NiCd is liable to be about 500 mAh and may be less.
0.1 C at 500 mAh = 50 mA.
4V x 50 mA = 200 mW rated PC power.
You can buy say 300 mW 4V panels in 500 quantity for around $US1 in China.

Available solar energy is a longish subject in its own right and well enough covered in other SE answers. Look at www.gaisma.com for an idea of how many equivalent SSH (sunshine-hours) a day you can expect. A useful rule of thumb that is close enough for many areas is 2 SSH a day in winter and about 5 in summer. When dimensioning energy available from batteries you use 2 SSH.

By the time you have moved energy from panel to battery and battery to load you'll be lucky to get 50%  of notional panel energy out. Working in mAh can give you a better feel. A say 4V 50 mAA Imp panel will deliver 100 mAh in 2 hours of full sun. You'll get much but not all of that out of the battery - say 60-75 mAh, and then you lose energy if you need to convert to another voltage to drive the load. End to end you can typically assume the equivalent of Vbattery mean x 50 mAh for load use. Note that with NiCd you start out at somewhere above 1.2V/cell when fully charged and end up at 1V or so when almost discharged. A lightly loaded cell will be close to 1.2V across much of its life - so in winter a 200 mW panel may give 120 - 150 mWh of energy from 2 equivalent hours of sun.  I understand that this is well above the mean energy level that you need in this application -  so a much less than 200 mW panel should be adequate.

Even on ebay you can get acceptable prices for small volumes.

eg [this seller](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1-1W-6V-Mini-Solar-Panel-Module-Solar-System-Solar-Epoxy-Charger-DIY-/251504887923?tfrom=261452475871&tpos=top&ttype=coupon&talgo=undefined) is offering panels at prices well below the one you showed.
[This panel rated at 6V 100 mA](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/6V-100mA-Mini-Solar-Panel-Module-Solar-System-Solar-Epoxy-Charger-DIY/261452475871?_trksid=p2047675.c100012.m1985&_trkparms=aid%3D444000%26algo%3DSOI.DEFAULT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140107090229%26meid%3D7869163876102750910%26pid%3D100012%26prg%3D20140107090229%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D251504887923) costs about $5.

Comment: In volume, you can buy a panel I mentioned in my first post for $0.85 including shipping or $0.65 without shipping

Comment: @Jim - Yes. Prices vary widely amongst suppliers and with available technology. I mentioned "about a dollar" for a 300 mW panel. That is for a PET surfaced panel (with long life US SOURCED PET used)(Macdirmid) rather than an epoxy one and from a supplier who is able and willing to produce a quality product and to guarantee the performance levels of all panels in a batch. Epoxy is OK for occasional outdoor use or short lifetimes but degrades rapidly under all day every day outdoor use. (The carbon-carbon bonds in epoxy are not resistant to solar UV).

Answer (score 0):

Search for energy harvesting and look for IC's that are made to charge batteries.  They typically work with much lower voltages (ie from a solar cell) and can boost them to the required voltage for charging.

I have briefly read about them but some appear to include battery management functionality which will monitor/manage the charging of the cells

The chip you have found looks promising since it is aimed towards your application

Comment: With solar it's not just about boosting, [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/usb-dc-and-solar-lipoly-charger/design-notes) is an interesting article if you're interested.

Comment: Also, for the most efficient charging read about [Maximum Power Point Tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking).

Comment: Interesting, for solar and MPPT I think I would want to use a buck boost dc/dc converter.  I thought I found a chip that was geared for this so that even in very low light conditions it would still boost to charge.  I can't find the link again right now but I suspect it was a TI part.  The adafruit page shows them talking about buck vs linear which will stop charging when not in great light conditions if I am not mistaken